# Is it necessary to filter out New Relic site availability pings from Google Analytics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-analytics, newrelic

New Relic lists its User-Agent header and IP addresses here:

```
https://newrelic.com/docs/alerts/availability-monitoring
```

The User-Agent header is

```
NewRelicPinger/1.0 (your_account_id)
```

But unfortunately, I couldn't find any consensus on a way to simply filter Google Analytics by a given user agent header.  So, I'm wondering, does one need to block New Relic from GA results when New Relic is set up to check site availability?  I've already filtered my Papertrail logs, because it was annoying to see the requests showing up every 5-10 seconds.  In Google Analytics, I see some strange location results coming in, and I think it may be related to NR, but I'm not sure.  Since I didn't find a single article mentioning any of this, I wondered whether Google automatically knows to filter NR pings or something, perhaps due to its User-Agent header.  Anyone know whether it needs to be done manually, or should it be left alone in Google Analytics?  I would think this would be pretty relevant since both New Relic and GA are going to be par for the course in many Heroku/Rails setups, along with the great availability monitoring feature.

Along that same line, does anyone know whether, when setting a filter on a GA account, does that filter apply to all reports both proactively and retroactively in a non-destructive way?  Or does it only begin to filter results moving forwards, in a destructive way (e.g., hard-filtering the results and not saving filtered/excluded data at all)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Analytics relies on Javascript to collect metrics. I'm pretty sure the client New Relic uses to ping your site will not execute Javascript on the page, and for that reason the pings should not show up in Google Analytics.

Comment: To expand on this answer, applying filters does not fix your data retroactively. But the filter is not needed in this case to begin with.

Comment: Great point; I hadn't thought about them not using a full browser to do the pings.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Most monitoring services don't execute javascript, and if this is the case with New Relic, then no need to filter.

To determine whether or not New Relic does appear in your GA data, use the Audience > Technology > Browser & OS report. Google analytics uses the user-agent string as the browser, so you should see a line item for NewRelicPinger if it is a problem.

[image]

Regarding your filters question, a filter will only act moving forwards, in a destructive way. Once data is filtered, there is no way to recover it, and there is no way to filter out data that has already been collected (although an advanced segment can usually be applied if necessary).

Comment: An excellent answer, too; definitely gets an upvote from me; I would have given it the accepted answer check but friism knew definitively about NR not using JS, so I guess that gave it the nudge.  Regardless, thanks for the answer, and I appreciate the helpful advice on using the Browser Report; I'd forgotten that reports the user-agent string.  Kudos!